# Why does preg_match_all() create the same answer multiple times?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

The following code extracts #hashtags from a tweet and puts them in the variable $matches.

```
$tweet = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";

preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $tweet, $matches);

var_dump( $matches );
```

Can someone please explain to me why the following results have **2 identical arrays instead of just 1**?

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#hashtag"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "#badhash"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "#goodhash_tag"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#hashtag"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "#badhash"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "#goodhash_tag"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you use `()` to catch the sub group.

Try:

```
preg_match_all("/#\w+/", $tweet, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using () unless you want it to do exactly that. lol Sorry, that came out not so friendly :(

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php Example 3

Answer (score 0):

**its simple :**

remove `()` from your expression

Hope it helps.